# Jacoco support for apache wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm deal with `Hybris` project with Apache Wicket. Does `Jacoco` support Apache Wicket tests?(specific tests for UI rendering) I didn't find anything about this. Or maybe the are some plugins for this? What test coverage tool choose for Apache Wicket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacoco does code coverage, so every line of java that is touched by the tests from `WicketTester` is covered.

We use it a lot. It does not do anything with the generated HTML itself.